# Accessing nth element of a nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following JS array:

```
let text = [
{
  line: [{
    words: [{
      word: [
        { letter: 'H' },
        { letter: 'i' },
        { letter: ' ' },
      ],
    },
    {
      word: [
        { letter: 'J' },
        { letter: 'i' },
        { letter: 'm' },
        { letter: '\n' },
      ],
    }],
  }]
},
{
  line: [{
    words: [{
      word: [
        { letter: 'H' },
        { letter: 'i' },
        { letter: ' ' },
      ],
    },
    {
      word: [
        { letter: 'J' },
        { letter: 'o' },
        { letter: '\n' },
      ],
    }],
  }]
}
```

]

Is there a fast (and simple) way to access the nth letter?
For example :

- if n=0, get 'H'
- if n=1, get 'i'
- ...
- if n=11, get 'o'

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/6usdej75/

Comment: i feel like somethig can be done using modulo arithmetic. ehh on second thought maybe not

Comment: Define _**fast**_

Comment: Have you tried Array.prototype.flatMap?

Comment: A line may have `words` or `word`?

Comment: @SalmanA My mistake, I updated the question. Fast means faster than getting the nth child in the DOM  ;-)

Comment: @soupy-norman  not sure Array.prototype.flatMap is appropriated.If so, I don't understand how.

Comment: @Fifi trivial with flatMap if its a feasible option . `text.flatMap(x => x.line).flatMap(x => x.words).flatMap(x => x.word)[n].letter`

Comment: I'd reduce this structure into a single string, then simply use the accessor to get the character you need. (`result[n]`)

Comment: Fastest solution would be the one that _stops_ at the nth letter. Solutions suggesting flatMap will iterate whole data even if you requested 0th item. Besides, there is added complexity, some letters are 3 level deep, some are 4.

Comment: i guess a while loop with count

Comment: Since `words` (plural) seems to be optional I suppose you need handle the event when there is no such property like such `text.flatMap(t => t.line.flatMap(l => l.words?.flatMap(w => w.word) ?? l.word)).map(w => w.letter)`

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue, the fastest option (if possible) is to keep an index of the object like in databases.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with `flat` and `flatMap`:

```js
let text = [
  {
    line: [{
      words: [{
        word: [
          { letter: 'H' },
          { letter: 'i' },
          { letter: ' ' },
        ],
      },
      {
        word: [
          { letter: 'J' },
          { letter: 'i' },
          { letter: 'm' },
          { letter: '\n' },
        ],
      }],
    }]
  },
  {
    line: [{
      words: [{
        word: [
          { letter: 'H' },
          { letter: 'i' },
          { letter: ' ' },
        ],
      },
      {
        word: [
          { letter: 'J' },
          { letter: 'o' },
          { letter: '\n' },
        ],
      }],
    }]
  }
];

const flat = text.map(({ line }) => line.map(({ words }) => words.map(({ word }) => word)).flatMap(item => item.flat())).flat();
function getIndex(array, index) {
  return array[index];
}
console.log(getIndex(flat, 0));
console.log(getIndex(flat, 1));
console.log(getIndex(flat, 11));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good option is to use any loop to break it at the index you need:

```js
let text = [
{
  line: [{
    words: [{
      word: [
        { letter: 'H' },
        { letter: 'i' },
        { letter: ' ' },
      ],
    },
    {
      word: [
        { letter: 'J' },
        { letter: 'i' },
        { letter: 'm' },
        { letter: '\n' },
      ],
    }],
  }]
},
{
  line: [{
    words: [{
      word: [
        { letter: 'H' },
        { letter: 'i' },
        { letter: ' ' },
      ],
    },
    {
      word: [
        { letter: 'J' },
        { letter: 'o' },
        { letter: '\n' },
      ],
    }],
  }]
}
];

console.log( findLetter(text, 0) );
console.log( findLetter(text, 1) );
console.log( findLetter(text, 11) );

function findLetter(text = [], index = 0) {
  let i = 0;
  for (let {line} of text) {
    for (let {words} of line) {
      for (let {word} of words) {
        if (word.length + i <= index) {
          i += word.length;
        } else {
          return word[index - i].letter;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```